# bilinear form over field of char 2

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Im struggling to understand what bilinear symmetric forms and quadratic forms represent over a field, I understand the theory behind it, but I cant apply it.

For example I was given this exercise, which look simple and I get the intuition behind it, but I cant solve it concretely.

Find a non zero bilinear symmetric form such that its quadratic form associated is equal to $0$, for characteristic $2$

Comment: how can I write a bilinear symmetric form over $\mathbb F^{2}$

Comment: See Arf Invariants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arf_invariant#Quadratic_forms_over_F2

Comment: could you verify my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, can someone verify my answer:

I define the bilinear symmetric form $f : \mathbb F_2^{2} \to \mathbb F_2$$:f((1,0),(1,0))=0 , f((1,0),(0,1))=1 , f((0,1),(0,1))=0$ which is non-zero and the matrix associated to the quadratic form obtained via $f$ is $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

which gives the quadratic form $2xy$ which is always equal to $0$ since we are in $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: I think the bilinear symmetric form is not well defined though

Comment: I couldn't read your answer before and I posted exactly the same thing: why wouldn't it be well defined? Yes, it is well defined.

Comment: @DonAntonio It does seem fine, except that it is claimed to have incorrect domain and codomain.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Indeed so, thanks. Well, it is either a deep misunderstanding of the OP, or else just a simple typo

Comment: @JonathanBaram The function you're defining should be $\;f: \Bbb F_2\times\Bbb F_2=\Bbb F_2^{(2)}\to\Bbb F_2\;$ . That $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ has no business there, imo. With $\;\Bbb F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=$ the field with two elements.

Comment: it was a misunderstanding. thanks for clarifying this